# java script организация кода

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как можно организовать код как бы по компонентам если я пишу на нативном java script без фреймворков, то есть делать один JS файл на весь проект слишком длинно и непонятно, если на каждый компонент делать свой JS файл то как их правильно подгружать если в добавок ко всему я использую идею single page application.

Надеюсь суть понятно описал=)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При текущем состоянии веба наилучшим вариантом оказывается использование webpack

Comment: я самоучка и уже потратил слишком много времени, а проект хочу доделать, для меня фреймворки оказались сложнее чем сами языки и не кажутся такими удобными. всетаки хотелось бы решить задачу без потери еще одного месяца на изучение какой то удобной штуки

Comment: Вы потратите времени намного больше для написания своей удобной штуки. Зато прокачаетесь. Решать вам)

Comment: Проблема, которую вы описали, является ключевой проблемой всего JS. Тот функционал, который предоставляет Webpack, должен предоставляться на уровне языка, а не фреймворков. Но увы, JS не был спроектирован под одностраничные приложения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Лирическое отступление:** Я так предполагаю, что вы еще не дошли, до того уровня, чтобы устроиться на какую-либо оплачиваемую работу программистом или стать полноценным фрилансером. Но я также предполагаю то, что у вас есть огромное желание этого добиться, так как вы сами пытаетесь во всем разбираться. В связи с этим хотел бы вам дать пару советом на счет этого(возможно многие будут со мной не согласны):

- *Работодателю нужен качественный результат за как можно меньшее количество времени.* Этим я хочу сказать то, что мало кто-то из заказчиков согласится ждать, пока вы будете писать свой "фреймворк", так как это долго и чревато ошибками(который уже в большинстве случаев отлажены и исправлены в большинстве библиотек), в связи с этим, мы можем видеть такое большое количество различных требований, на счет знания библиотек и фреймворков, помимо самого языка, технологий и прикладной области, в объявлениях по устройстве на работу. Сейчас знаний только языка программирования недостаточно...
- *Если у вас все получается, значит вы занимаетесь не тем.* Здесь я подразумеваю то, что в области программирования, не бывает такого, чтобы вы что-то выучили и до пенсии хватило данных знаний для решения определенных задач... На самом же деле, вам постоянно приходится изучать что-то новое и весьма трудное, решать сложные проблемы на которые порой трудно найти ответы(наверное из-за этого мы все любим этим заниматься). Поэтому не бойтесь брать трудные задачи и решать их, пусть это будет занимать очень много времени, но пользы от этого будет гораздо больше, чем от решения многих примитивных задач.
- *Пишите свое, когда вы знаете как это должно выглядеть и работать.* Вы написали то ,не зная о том, как это работает и как это довести до ума, а не знаете потому, что вы не работали с этим. Если бы у вас был бы подобный опыт работы с такими библиотеками, то все было бы гораздо проще.

Конечно, разбираться в том, как там все устроено внутри очень интересно и полезно(что греха таить, я и сам любитель таких вещей), но приступать к этому нужно после определенного фундамента, т.е. понимая того как это реализовывается и самое главное как это нужно реализовать.

**Ответ на вопрос:** Приведу два возможных решения на мой взгляд:

- *Пишем все сами.* Самым простым решением будет использование транспилятора JS кода. Для этого вы устанавливает Node.js инициализируете проект, и используете  `require`  и `import` для многофайловой архитектуры вашего кода, а после транспилируете данный код в пригодный для браузера.
- *Используем мейнстримовые фреймворки и инструменты.* Взять и изучить любой из самых популярных JS фрейворков(например React, Angular, Vue, ...) и конечно какую-либо популярную систему сборки(Webpack, Gulp, ...) и поверьте мне, после этого у вас не останется вопросов связанных с этой темой, вы все это поймете в процессе изучения.

Comment: решил воткнуться в ангуляр=)

Comment: Желаю удачи в изучении)